# What is the C# equivalent of Swift's URL struct in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.iOS and I am working with NSAttributeString.

I need to know if a link attribute contains an URL.
I found a Swift code to do that: `if let url = value as? URL` but I don't know what C# class represent 'URL'.

From what I can understand URL and NSUrl are different, so I cannot use the latter.
It there a naming pattern for those Swift structures?

Comment: Are you after `System.Uri` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URL` is just an "overlay" of `NSURL` and since Xamarin.iOS is directly using Objective-C APIs, you should just use the `NSURL` reference type directly.

- "Swift-based" URL:

> An object representing the location of a resource that bridges to URL; use NSURL when you need reference semantics or other Foundation-specific behavior.

- NSURL:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the URL structure, which bridges to the NSURL class."

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl

> The URL value type offers the same functionality as the NSURL reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation classes."

Comment: Thank you! I was reading that one is a class and one is a struct so I was confused. But casting it to NSUrl works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) and try this approach:

```
bool isUriCorrect = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("https://www.stackoverflow.com", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Advised method `IsWellFormedUriString()` indicates whether the string is well-formed by attempting to construct a URI with the string and ensures that the string does not require further escaping.